# POST form with JavaScript object (data)

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

I have form to add post where's title, description fields and one hidden field.
Post has many subcontents (text, photo, video).

Now, every new subcontent (as Javascript object (hash)) is added to Javascript array variable. After click submit button, array variable is moved to hidden field value and form send request to create new post (with title, description and field with subcontents).

It's any safe way to do this (eg. now hacker can add subcontent via JS Console without validation check)?

Comment: you should probably add a validation layer on the backend, too.

Comment: Of course, I added.
But I think that current subcontents storage way is not good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anybody can add any data to any POST, with javascript or not. I can use `curl` to submit whatever data I want to your server. It's up to your server-side application to filter out the bad stuff and validate the good stuff.

Comment: But you know better way to store subcontents?

Comment: Not specifically. But don't get too caught up on client-side security. Strengthen the security on the server-side.